# asp.net authenticate from domain login

Tags: asp.net

I have windows authentication enabled on my asp.net page. When I navigate to the page it asks me to login. How would I get this prompt to go away if the user is logged onto the domain?

Sorry but I wasn't sure how to ask this or what to search.

in web config

```
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something similar. Just so you know, we have a separate application for users which use domain login and for those which use an integrated application login. I was just checking through the differences, and turns out, we didn't need to do almost anything for it to work:

We've commented out our custom Membership provider and the

```
<!-- <authentication mode="Forms">
    ...
</authentication> -->
```

tag. Instead we set the authentication method in IIS to Windows Authentication and disabled Forms Authentication. - But I guess setting authentication in web.config should also work.

However the automated domain login only works while using Internet Explorer. we didn't manage to make it work with any other browser.